# Is there any blog post which can guide me to use ui-router with angular components?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-1.5, angular-components

i am looking to transform Angular app with 1.5, but we have used the `ngComponentRouter`. As its been deprecated , i am looking to shift to the `ui-router`. But, if we make dumb components, so i was thinking how we can incorporate these with `ui-router`.

Please suggest any blog that can help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui-router 1.0 is in beta now and will be stable in a couple of weeks from what I've heard. In this version, states have a component property to route directly to components.

The latest API docs are linking to [the 1.0 version](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/)

```
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('hello', {
        url: '/hello',
        component: 'hello'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2627 for more info. Probably this is in alpha version right now.

IMHO you can use classic component and link its template in "templateUrl" when defining your state.